# 401 on public vfpage of partner Site if am arealdy logged in customer Site

Tags: force.com-sites, authentication

I created a VF page, configured to be public under the Partner Site.

When I am not logged in anywhere, I get the page fine.

When I logged in Partner Site with some partner contact, I get the page fine.

When I logged in force.com (internal users), I get the page fine.

But, when I am logged in another Force.com Site (say for my Customers) with a customer contact, the page is not opening - I am redirected to the login page of the Partner Site.

When I am logged in Customer Portal and browse a public page of Partner Site, I want / am expecting to see the page, as a guest, because I am not logged in Partner Site. How can I make this scenario happen?

Note: I tried the other way around (public page in customer site, me logged in partner site) and got the same 401/login page response.

Both Sites are Communities having Administration/Template=Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce

Comment: Are both of these SFDC Communities?  Are you using Templates (Napili, etc.) or VF+Tabs?

Comment: Yes both are SFDC Communities, both showing Administration/Settings/Template = Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce

Answer (score 0):

No You need to add in your partner user's profile to access it there. Salesforce has different security permission at different level. You need to give permission at all level.

So just go to their profile and scroll down and you will see a section Visualforce page and add your page there.

Comment: ==> same issue

1.I added every possible profiles to my vfpage (Enable Profile Access for Visualforce Page).

2.logout / closed all my browser

3.logged as Customer contact to Customer Site

4.browse my public page in Partner Site

Comment: @Jean-PierreDery I think because you are logged in in same browser then SF might accesing same cookies to access another site and then it is giving you this error. Try to access some other public page

Comment: So you are thinking a Salesforce limitation?

Comment: @Jean-PierreDery not 100% sure but yes.